# Registration in Draw mode is very delayed and inaccurate

Tags: animation, grease-pencil, draw-mode

I'm just beginning to use Blender as a storyboarding program, and was hoping to be able to use the 3d features in Blender to give me better camera control and better use of environment in my scenes. However, no matter what I try, the draw feature is so laggy and sloppy, it makes any efforts to draw in Blender pointless.

I first tried using it in the last version (2.82), then upgraded to the newest version (2.83) with no effect. 
It seems to have the same issue whether I use the mouse or my Wacom Cintiq.

The problem is consistent regardless of any smoothing adjustments or settings I've tried, and gives the same results whether I'm drawing a regular stroke, or a grease pencil object.

[Here's a video demonstrating the problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JgMfyEWnMCQ)

I've been researching this for 2 days solid, but haven't found anything to mitigate the issue, or prove whether it's a setting I can fix, or a bug involving my system, or Blender itself. I've watched other people using the pencil and grease pencil tools and I seem to be the only one having this issue.

If this is common, and the fix is to just draw much slower than I normally would, then that would also answer my question of whether Blender is a suitable program for storyboarding. I would appreciate any answers that anyone has to offer. 
Thank you!

Comment: I use blender's grease pencil for storyboarding and don't get that. It doesn't look like an issue with blender, but with the drivers/settings for the tablet. On wacom tablets a common problem happens if pen has been dropped  and the nib of the pen is not set correctly. Try pulling the nib out of the pen and re-set it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I was hoping to get a fellow storyboarder on the hook- I'm glad to hear it's not a consistent issue. I'll check on the drivers, but the pen works perfectly fine in other programs, and I haven't had any issues with the Pro Pen2. 

I'm thinking you're right about the wacom driver though, I'll see if restarting the driver, or reverting to older versions helps.

Comment: Update: 
- I updated my Mac OS from Mojave to Catalina- no effect.
- Uninstalled and reinstalled Wacom drivers for my Cintiq - no effect.
- Deleted any existing files left over from older versions of Blender, and reinstalled the latest version - no effect.

- I went back and installed the Blender 2.79b-macOS-10.6 AND DRAWING WORKED PERFECTLY!

I don't want to constantly use an expired version of Blender with a completely different interface, and now I no the version is part of the issue. 

SO... how can I solve this for the newer version?

Comment: It might be a bug. If it was working on previous versions and not now something changed.

Comment: @Shadyace Have you found your solution? not sure if this help, but my case is I am using tablet called XPPen and in 2.82 too I have issue. After much of test, I realise that the pressure sensor did cost the delay. The new tablet have 2048 pressure sensitivity, so I tweak the tablet sensitivity curve so that the max is 512(old tablet setting), then it works much better. But I still get delay while using cycle preview mode.